# Do "multiplicative" current mirrors exist?

Tags: voltage, transistors, circuit-analysis, current

What I am talking about is something like a mismatched current mirror. Like the following where the left transistor and the right transistor are unmatched therefore the drain source current are different by a factor K. Is this possible?

[image: circuit]

Comment: Yep. Integrated on silicon all the time. With one reference and multiple outputs of different values even.

Comment: Sure. If they're integer ratios you could just use multiple exactly similar transistors connected in parallel.

Comment: So current Iref could be flowing on the left and on the right a current KIref would be flowing?

Comment: If there are n transistors on the left and m transistors on the right (in parallel) then the current on the right would be (m/n)*Iref.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're designing the actual silicon, you do this by making the two MOSFETs with different W/L ratios.

If you're designing with discretes, you can do it by including resistors between the FET source pins and ground, and adjusting the resistor values to give the desired current ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Bipolar ICs did this (in the 70s) by building current mirror transistors with multiple emitters. Ratios of 5:1 were common. A good discussion can be found at http://www.righto.com/2016/12/inside-lm108-op-amp-superbeta.html